# Android copy values from table and insert in another

Tags: android, sqlite, copy

I'm trying to copy all the data in a database table, which correspond to the WHERE clause, and insert them into another table. I'm trying this code, but in the table `prev` there are only 2 records in the table `Ver` are inserted more than 100 records .... why?

```
private void Tras() {

 String numero_ricevuto = (i.getStringExtra("numero"));
 SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 String sql = "SELECT data, unita_di_misura FROM prev WHERE numero ='"+numero_ricevuto+"'";
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
 int count = c.getCount();
 String[] data = new String[count];
 String[] unita_di_misura = new String[count];
 for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
   c.moveToNext();  
   data[i] = c.getString(0);
   unita_di_misura[i] = c.getString(1);
  }            

  for(int i=0 ;i < data.length;i++){
   ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
   cv.put(VerTable.SI_NO, "0");
   cv.put(VerTable .DATA, data[i]);
   cv.put(VerTable .U_M, e.unita_di_misura[i]);
   db.insert(VerTable .TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }
 c.close();
 db.close();
}
```

Comment: what is VerTable.SI_NO ?

Comment: What is name of you second table where you want to copy data and also give structure of that table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 3 line solution hope this will help you

```
private void Tras() {

        String numero_ricevuto = (i.getStringExtra("numero"));
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO "+VerTable .TABLE_NAME+" SELECT 0,data, unita_di_misura FROM prev WHERE numero = '"+numero_ricevuto+"'";
        db.execSQL(sql);

        db.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> but in the table prev there are only 2 records in the table Ver are inserted more than 100 records .... why?

Possibly you ran the code more than once.

Also, pulling data from db only to insert it back is not very efficient. It's better to let the database engine do the work for you, e.g.

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + VerTable.TABLE_NAME +
  "(" + VerTable.SI_NO + "," VerTable.DATA + "," + VerTable.U_M + ") " +
  "SELECT 0, data, unita_di_misura FROM prev WHERE numero=?",
  new String[] { numero_ricevuto });
```

Using `?` params also avoids the possiblity of string SQL injection.

Comment: But I get an error `"E / SQLiteLog (2523): (1) no such column: data 
. "` Field data exists. Why this?